# Perl CGI get multipart/form-data file contents without temp file

Tags: perl, upload, cgi

In perl is there a lib/package for getting the file upload data directly to a scalar without going through a 'tmp' file. My form is like:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="myfile">
</form>
```

I could not figure out how to get the data using the CGI module without going through a temporary file. I can read the full contents on stdin, but I don't want to have to re-invent the wheel decoding multipart data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at CGI->upload function

```
my $fh = $cgi->upload('data');
{
   # enable 'slurp' mode
   local $/;
   $data = <$fh>;                                                                                                                                    
}
```